Updating a column in a table in Indian Numbering System
How to update a table having a column name as amount in number data type to comma separated digits followingenter image description here Indian Numbering System
I tried this code block:
UPDATE sep
SET amount = TO_CHAR(amount, '999,999,999')

And got the error like:
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.

I am expecting my to should look, while updating, exactly like the above image.

A NUMBER data-type is stored in a proprietary format with one byte for the scale (exponent) and then one byte for each two-significant-digits. It does NOT store any formatting.
Therefore, you cannot store a number with formatting (if you want to do that then you would need to store the numbers as strings and not as a number - but don't do that).
Instead, when you want to display a number then you can use TO_CHAR to apply the formatting when you query the table.
SELECT TO_CHAR(amount, '999G999G999') AS amount
FROM   sep

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE sep (amount) AS
SELECT  100000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2300000 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



AMOUNT




     100,000


   2,300,000



fiddle
